# Run Ant files when performing Build and Deploy Worklight 5.x.x Application

Tags: eclipse, ant, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I have a Worklight application set up in Eclipse. Before executing *Build And Deploy Worklight Application*, I need to run a bat that compiles a bunch of HTML templates. This templates are necessary to run the app correctly.

So, I would like to know if it is possible to **link** (maybe under *Run Configurations...*?) an Ant file or similar that allows me to execute the bat and perform the build & deploy in an automatic way. Any advice?

Hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can add an extra project builder to your application that invokes the Ant task you need.

Under Eclipse take a look at *Project->Properties->Builders->New*.

You will find [Ant buildfiles as project builders](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-92_project_builders.htm?cp=0_1_2_1) a useful link.

Comment: Thanks for the helps. I figured it out!!