# Run an Ant file with Worklight 6.x.x within Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, ant, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

Returning back to my previous question written in [Run Ant files when performing Build and Deploy Worklight 5.x.x Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011769/run-ant-files-when-performing-build-and-deploy-worklight-5-x-x-application) where I received a correct reponse, now I need to run an Ant file when executing *Build And Deploy Worklight Application* with Worklight 6.x.x.

The previous solution works well with Worklight 5.x.x but now it seems that with Worklight 6.x.x things have changed a little bit. The building order is not the same as previous and so the Ant file is not executed anymore.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an open defect in Worklight 6.0.0.x and 6.1.0.x.

There is currently no workaround for it.